# Changing alignment of specific items along the main axis

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Given the following structure:

```
<header>
  <button>First</button>
  <button>Second</button>
  <button>Third</button>
  <button>Fourth</button>
  <button>Fifth</button>
</header>
```

Is there any way to get the last three buttons to align themselves to the `main-end` of the flex container? My understanding is according to this diagram:

[image: Flexbox Diagram]

I've tried the following, but it aligns items along the cross axis instead of the main axis:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
header button:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

`main-end` is not a valid value for `align-self`, but that is the effect I want to achieve. Is this possible without any additional dom structure?

ASCII diagram of the desired effect for good measure:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|-------------------+                                          +------------------------|
||        ||        |                                          |      ||       ||      ||
||        ||        |                                          |      ||       ||      ||
||        ||        |                                          |      ||       ||      ||
|-------------------+                                          +------------------------|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Edit:** I would prefer to avoid floats if at all possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can align the last three with [auto margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#auto-margins) by using:

```
header button:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zr1w4kaq/)

Comment: Nice! Here's a link to a Codepen with autoprefixer enabled to make it work in Safari: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Fbghf